# Qual estrutura arquitetural é utilizada nesse site?

Tags: debate

Queria saber as principais decisões de projeto foram tomadas na criação do Stackoverflow e qual a sua estrutura arquitetural.
Se é uma estrutura baseado em camadas, ou baseado em objetos distribuídos, ou se é baseado em eventos – Modelo Publish/Subscriber, ou baseado em dados -compartilhamento de espaço de dados.
Qual o seu estilo arquitetural?

Comment: você pode olhar esta palestra: [A Arquitetura do Stack Overflow e Stack Exchange](http://www.infoq.com/br/presentations/a-arquitetura-do-stack-overflow-e-stack-exchange), mas em resumo, esqueça estas coisas de livro, e pense em desempenho.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10369/140010

Comment: Isto não foi já perguntado?